# Seq of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

> Let the seq ${X(n)}$, ${Y(n)}$ are divergent. Then
>
> > 1. The seq ${X(n)+Y(n)}$ may or may not be convergent.
> > 2. The seq ${X(n)+Y(n)}$ always divergent.
> > 3. The seq ${X(n) •Y(n)}$ may or may not be convergent.
> > 4. The seq ${X(n)•Y(n)}$ is always divergent.

Answer (score 0):

$X_n=0$ for odd $n$ and 1 for even $n$, whilst $Y_n=1$ for odd $n$, 0 for even $n$. Then $X_n+Y_n$ diverges and $X_n\cdot Y_n$ converges.

If $X_n$ is as above, but $Y_n=X_n$, then $X_n+Y_n$ diverges and $X_n\cdot Y_n$ diverges.

If $X_n$ is as above, but $Y_n=-X_n$, then $X_n+Y_n$ converges and $X_n\cdot Y_n$ diverges.

So 1. and 3. are true.

Comment: Thank you....I'll be careful for the next tym...